# Print data-structure/ Data-type hierarchy

Tags: python, data-structures

Let's assume we have a Data-Structure which consists of nested Data-Types, is there a way of printing the data-types like:

```
Dict()<List()<Dict()>>
```

**Example Data-Structure with Values:**

```
complexDataStructure = {"FirstDict":[{"AnotherDict":[[1,2,3],[1,2,3] ]}  , {"OneMoreDict":[[1,2,3],[1,2,3] ]}  ]}

>>> output Dict()<List()<Dict()>>
```

You can see the nested Structure with its Values, I would like to print the  Data-types in a similar way and thought about an recursive approach, but not every data-structures are iterable (like `set()` ) or not all values can be accessed with slicing (`dict()`)

Comment: Not sure what you want. Could you give us more examples? Like "when the input is ..., the expected output is ....".

Comment: Thanks for your Comment, i try to figure out all data types in a nested datastructure.

Comment: Let's try a simpler case first. When the input is `[{}, []]`, what output do you expect?

Comment: List()<Dict(), List()>

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if the following fits your requirements:

```
def ppt(data):
    if isinstance(data, int):
        return "Int()"
    elif isinstance(data, str):
        return "Str()"
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        if len(data) == 0:
            return "List()"
        else:
            return "List()<" + ", ".join([ppt(item) for item in data]) + ">"
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        if len(data) == 0:
            return "Dict()"
        else:
            return "Dict()<" + ", ".join([ppt(data[key]) for key in data]) + ">"
    else:
        return "Unknown()"
```

When the input is `[{}, []]` the output is indeed `List()<Dict(), List()>`:

```
>>> print(ppt([{}, []]))
List()<Dict(), List()>
```

But when the input is your `complexDataStructure` the output is:

```
Dict()<List()<Dict()<List()<List()<Int(), Int(), Int()>, List()<Int(), Int(), Int()>>>, Dict()<List()<List()<Int(), Int(), Int()>, List()<Int(), Int(), Int()>>>>>
```

which is different from your `Dict()<List()<Dict()>>`, but in my opinion is more accurate. Please give me feedback if you have something else in mind.